# Function Attribute on Lambda with Explicit Return Type fails to Compile

Tags: c++, g++

The following program fails to compile in g++ 9.1 and 9.2 (with `--std=c++17`):

```
int main()
{
    auto foo = [&]() __attribute__((always_inline)) -> bool { return true; };
}
```

With the following error:

```
file.cpp: In lambda function:
file.cpp:3:53: error: expected '{' before '->' token
    3 |     auto foo = [&]() __attribute__((always_inline)) -> bool { return true; };
      |                                                     ^~
file.cpp: In function 'int main()':
file.cpp:3:53: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'main()::<lambda()>'
file.cpp:3:56: error: expected unqualified-id before 'bool'
    3 |     auto foo = [&]() __attribute__((always_inline)) -> bool { return true; };
      |                                                        ^~~~
```

This program successfully compiles with g++ 4.7 to 8.3, as well as clang++ from 3.5 to 9.0. Is this a GCC bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Write this way  auto foo = [&]() -> bool __attribute__((always_inline)) { return true; };

Comment: That syntax is meant to apply attributes to the type, not the function.

Comment: A type can not be inlined.

Comment: I know, that's why that syntax doesn't work for function attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is GCC bug [Bug 90333 - [9 Regression] Can't apply attributes to lambdas with trailing returns](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90333) . It was introduced with [R265787](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=265787) and is slated as fixed in 9.3.